# How do I pull only the customer name with three or more transactions?

Tags: sql

I want to return only the transactions for customer name `ABC` and `EFG`.

[image: data in a table]

Comment: Try SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE name = 'ABC' AND name = 'EFG'

Comment: @sqlnoob please see my below answer. It will solve your problem.

Comment: @sqlnoob also please update your question either update your question title. anyone know what you want to ask here.

Answer (score 1):

try like below by using aggregation

```
select name 
from table
group by name
having count(*)>=3
```

Comment: I think you may have just done sqlnoob's homework assignment.

Comment: The actual data has 20 columns and 1,000+ rows. How would I get it to only display the customers with three or more transactions.

Answer (score 0):

Try below solution for your question statement. It will work

```
 SELECT * FROM table WHERE name in ('ABC' ,'EFG')
```

Try below for title of your question

```
 select name from table group by name having count(Amt) > =3
```

Comment: While this answers the question, it does not answer the TITLE of the question (3 or more transactions).